# directing a specific input in a form to update an array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so i have a form with multiple inputs, the form creates a post request on the server. I need a specific input in my html to push a value into an array thats stored in the schema. I understand that the request pertains to a specific route, and that all inputs react to this route as one, is there a way to break them up without creating a new post route for each input. The rateEmployee function is part of an exported object.

```js
rateEmployee: function(req, res){
  var employeeId = req.params.id
  Employees.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeId, {$push: {ratings: 1}}, {new: true}, (err, update) => {
    if(err){
     console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      console.log(update)
      res.redirect('/employers/view/' + req.user.id) 
        }
```

```html
<form method='post' action='/employers/<%= employee.id %>/employeeRate'>
  <div>Rate This Employee</div>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i>
  <input type='submit' id='one' value='1'>
  <input type='submit' id='two' value='2'>
  <input type='submit' id='three' value='3'>
  <input type='submit' id='four' value='4'>
  <input type='submit' id='five' value='5'>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Express's router are middlewares that bind to a specific route.You can bind multiple middlewares to the same route.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/post1', (req, res,next) => {
   let body=req.body;
   let rate = body.rate;
    next();
});

router.post('/post1', (req, res) => {
    res.json({status: 'success'});
});
```

They all will be called in order if you are passing the control by calling `next()`.

If you decided to break the chain then an response can be returned at any point, `res.json({//response});`.
So your form can pass any arbitrary no. of inputs to the same route but your middlewares bind to that route must have logic to decide who has the responsibility to handle the incoming request. To access your form data first register a proper parser (Json/url encoded) and then the data posted from your form will be available in your req.body.This data will be available to all the middlewares you pass through.

EDIT : Adding body parser and improving example

Comment: thanks, but then how do i grab a specific element in a document in all of this to extract the value? because there is no access to the html document. would i use something like req.body?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've expanded my answer to include that.